# Calculating the number of characters in each line of a file excluding space characters

Tags: python

```
inFile = open("reversedTestFile.txt") 
lines = inFile.readlines() 
for line in lines: 
    print (line) 



inFile.seek(0)
for line in inFile:
    x=len(line)
    print("Length of line: " + str(x))
    c = 0
    for i in line:
        if i !="":
            c+=x
    print("Number of non-space characters: " + str(c))
```

The output came out to be:
36
1296
36
1296..so on with those two numbers, which is wrong...
How can I change it to make the output come out: 27, 23, 31, 24....?

Comment: So what's wrong with just using `len()` - it will return you exactly the number of characters of a string (your line in this case) including 'non-space' characters.

Comment: `len(line)` would give the number of characters including the newline character

Comment: `i` can never be `""`

Comment: I think I got what you were asking, but your title sounds confusing. I reworded to make it more clear. If I didn't understand what you were asking, let me know and I'll roll-back my edit.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I wanted to print the characters of each line, then non-space characters and so on. Using a nested for loop

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you want to include **only** non-space characters, not 'including non-space characters' (*with other characters*), and for that the easiest way is to just split your string and sum the chunk sizes:

```
with open("reversedTestFile.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(sum(len(x) for x in line.split()))
```

Comment: I want to include the non-space characters

Comment: The above will include only non-space characters, common `len(line)` will count all characters. If you want something else, please be more clear.

Comment: @zwer `split()` handles single whitespace by default, not `\t` and `\n`. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Coldspeed - you are mistaken, `str.split()` will use white space characters, including `\t`, `\n` and `\r` for splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Each one of the answers so far will have count an extra character for the line break `\n`, or `\r\n`. If you would rather not count that, you can simple remove it from your string, or decrement the resulting value.

```
with open('reversedTestFile.txt','r') as f:
    results=[len(line.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')) for line in f.readlines()]

print(results)
```

Comment: I have to use nested for loop for this